# Sort array by value of another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have 2 array.
first:

```
$comment = Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [ 2] => 1 
    [ 3] => 8 
    [ 5] => 3 
    [ 6] => 2 
    [ 7] => 4 
         )
```

And I have a second array:

```
$item = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => Sed a est quis sem pellentesque luctus. ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [title] => There is no one who loves pain itself ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 5 [title] => There is no one who loves pain itself ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 6 [title] => Sed a est quis sem pellentesque luctus. ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 7 [title] => Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ) 
)
```

In the array "comment" key it is id in the array "item".
I want to sort array "item" for the value of array "comment".

For Example:

```
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [title] => There is no one who loves pain itself ) // value in $comment 8
[5] => Array ( [id] => 7 [title] => Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem )       // value in $comment 4
[3] => Array ( [id] => 5 [title] => There is no one who loves pain itself ) // value in $comment 3
...
```

I tried to sort using array_multisort but I could not do it.
Help solve this problem.

Comment: I cannot see how you can sort `$item` using `$comment` to get your given result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
// first merge the arrays

foreach ($item as $key => $tab) {
    $item[$key]["numComment"] = $comment[$tab["id"]];
}


// then sort

usort($item, function ($t1, $t2) {
    return $t2["numComment"] - $t1["numComment"];
});

var_dump($item);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a few hours of agony, you decide my problem.